# Is there any reward for making it to the highest rank in the Battle Chateau?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I like the idea of it and it kind of just throws money at you. I was just curious if there is any reward (like a TM or held item or Mega Stone or something) besides having access to a bunch of trainers that you can fight a lot?

Comment: If your question is game specific (i.e., not about a specific pokemon, move, item, ability, etc.), please use the XY tag instead of the generic 6th gen tag.

Comment: Ah ok. I have been trying to figure out the different between the two tags.

Comment: Yup, no worries! Keep up the quality questions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting to the second-highest rank (Marquis/Marchioness) and highest rank (Duke/Duchess) unlocks rematch battles with the Gym Leaders and the Elite Four. However, without Writs, the Elite Four actually end up using *lower-level* Pokemon (around 40). However, after using several Writs, the Champion can end up using up to level 80 Pokemon in a rematch battle.

Higher-rank trainers also have a chance of giving treasure items such as Big Pearls.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. I was really disappointed when I found out the Elite 4 didn't level after beating them the first time.

Comment: High rank sometimes give you also Stardust

Comment: The highest rank is Grand Duke/Grand Duchess. Also, all ranks sometimes give you items, the lower ones usually stuff like Pearls, with the items getting more expensive the higher the rank of the person you defeated.

Comment: There is also one Duke, who will give you a big Nugget after battle. I do not remember his name, sorry.

Comment: Just to throw it in there, you can also get pearl strings which sells for a decent amount of 7500. This one actually started becoming pretty common for me.